# Best way to create a vertical list of TextView-> EditTextVIew?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to create a vertical list of TextView -> EditTextView. I need this to create a little input form. I have tried to use 2 vertical linear layouts that are children of a horizontal linear layout. Then I add TextViews to the first container and EditableTextViews to the second. The problem is that height of a text view has nothing to do with height of a EditTextView so they do not get correctly aligned vertically. What is the best method to achieve this? Use a Table? I'm curious how people effectively achieve this.

Comment: TableLayout or RelativeLayout. Nesting LinearLayouts isn't the most efficient way - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you, you can Use a list view that contains a textView to the left and an Edit text to the right

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListItem1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ListView with a row layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListItem1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That will create a textview on the left side and an editext on the right, each will take up half of the available space.  (Adjust the weight numbers to give one more space than the other).

Answer (score 0):

use gravity to align center if you want  want..........

Comment: you can make in using relative layout as well but if want to go with Table layout only then see http://abcquick.blogspot.in/2010/03/tutorial-on-android-layout.html

Answer (score -1):

For example you can use vertical linear layout as parent and add to it many horizontal linear layouts each of which contains TextView and EditableTextView